# Excel sheet with list of servers and links to different Remote Desktops

Tags: microsoft-excel, remote-desktop, vba

I have found some code to execute Remote Desktop from Excel,

```
Sub RDP()
    Dim RetVal As Variant
    RetVal = Shell("c:\WIndows\System32\mstsc.exe " & Range("A1"), 1)
End Sub
```

I have many servers to administrate, and list them as such in my excel sheet:

```
ServerName    DBServer                APPServer

Server 1      10.21.40.20             10.21.40.24
```

This list is ever expanding, I am looking for a smart way to click any of these IP's like a link in excel and execute the above RDP code.

Hope this can be done efficiently using Macros.

Comment: I should imagine you can achieve something like this. But tell me, what have you tried?

Comment: Have posted my solution that i've managed to create myself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much trying here's how to do it:

IP's of servers are located in column B and C, then Username and Passwords are in column D and E.

After double clicking the IP the correct username and password credentials are stored, then RDP is launched.

This is confirmed to be working!

Thanks everyone.

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
        Dim RetVal As Variant
        If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

           If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B999")) Is Nothing Or Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C999")) Is Nothing Then
                If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then

                     RetVal = Shell("cmdkey /generic:""" & Target & """ /user:""" & Target.Offset(0, 1) & """ /pass:""" & Target.Offset(0, 2) & """", 1)
                     RetVal = Shell("c:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe /admin /v:" & Target, 1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I pressed Alt - F7 and put this in the window that appeared.  Did I do the right thing?  It didn't work for me...  Could you help?